# How to read null terminated string from binary file using `ctypes`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, ctypes

I have a binary file created with sample c structure as below:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint16_t  field1;
    char*     field2;
    uint32_t  field3;
} data;
```

When this data is written in to binary, structure member `name` is always terminated with null character.

What would be efficient way to read such structure using ctypes?

I can read the structure if I know exact length as below:

```py
class Data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("field1", ctypes.c_uint16),
    ("field2", ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_char, 5)),
    ("field3", ctypes.c_uint32),
]
```

but that's the catch... I am not aware of the number of characters I would need to read from binary while reading using above structure.

Since there would be repeated adjacent data, I am looking from approach through which I can read character pointer data with null terminated string using ctypes preferably.

Comment: Is it going to be a one-time exercise ? :-)

Comment: you can say infrequent but definitely more than one time! I'm using it very weird alternatives as such, i.e. breaking structure of consistency and reading it as for loop..., it certainly is not readable solution to go.

Comment: I would say, write a C layer to convert it to a JSON representation and then read that in Python ?

Comment: The field `name` is not an array but a pointer. This begets the question how that is even serialized into the file?

Comment: That structure written as binary to a file would contain a pointer, not the actual data.  `name` should be a fixed-size array to be written properly.  Can you show the code that writes this structure?

Comment: Do it as you would in in *C*. If you have an array, then you no longer need the *total\_count* field. Didn't get the general usecase though.

Comment: all 3 fields would not correlate to give information so updated to generic field name.

Comment: @MarkTolonen for python script I get binary dump of data in which `field2` would ending length with null character. for me it does not matter how it is written from c code, but precisely how I can read in python in efficient and readable way.

Comment: If the data is *NUL* terminated, then the size field is redundant. If not, placing it after data, makes no sense (when reading the file).

Comment: @CristiFati I am aware of that, that is why I have the question, and specified that I know how to read if I know the size! (observer this statement in question -> `I can read the structure if I know exact length as below:`), since it is null terminated string, I am looking for examples for usage so that I can easily use it with ctypes structure

Comment: That statement doesn't shed any light (at least "*as below*" part), especially since you renamed the fields and one wouldn't know which one the size is (I remember before the edit that it was the last one). So the file is already created (meaning you can't change its structure)? I imagine the records in the file don't have the same length. Could the string contain *NUL* bytes?

Comment: I changed sample count filed [which wasn't size and thanks for bringing to attention so I corrected names with generic field name]. Agree, field record won't have same length. NUL character in string means end of string. others are fixed size data types hence no problem with those! since pointer type is only reference structure I have and understanding that end of string is null character

Comment: Ok, so this structure design (data length **after** (variable) data) is poor, not sure why anyone would do things so. Is like shooting self in the foot just before a running contest. If possible, correct it before going further. I see 2 ways: either read the string byte by byte until *NUL* is encountered (highly inefficient as disk reads are slow - leaving any buffering that might occur under the hood aside), or read chunks and iterate through them till *NUL* is found, but that would be more complicated since it would require moving the read pointer back after *NUL* position.

Comment: @CristiFati structure is read-only for me and this is just small snippet example out of whole structure.